# Octave Conditional Merging of matrices

Tags: join, matrix, merge, octave

I have searched for an Octave function that facilitates conditional merging of matrices but haven't one so far. My goal is to do this using vectors without looping. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
A= [1 1
    2 2
    3 1
    5 2];


B= [1 9
    2 10];
```

I would like to get `C` as

```
C= [1 1 9
    2 2 10
    3 1 9
    5 2 10];
```

Is there a function that takes `A`, `B` and the list of column(s) to join on and then produce `C`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [second output of `ismember`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Set-Operations.html#XREFismember) to find the occurrences of the second column of `A` in the first column of `B` and then use that to grab specific entries from the second column of `B` to construct `C`.

```
[~, inds] = ismember(A(:,2), B(:,1));   
C = [A, B(inds,2)];

%//   1     1     9
%//   2     2    10
%//   3     1     9
%//   5     2    10
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.